# Find out the subsequential limits of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $$x_n=(-1)^n \left(2+\frac{3^n}{n!}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right)$$ and find the upper and lower limits of the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$.

We put $n=1, 2, 3 \dots $ then $x_1=-9, x_2 = \frac{15}{2}, \dots $ after some stage we see that limit superior is $x_2$ and inferior is $x_1$ is it right?
Please explain.

Comment: do $x_{2n}$ and $x_{2n+1}$

Comment: The limit superior of a sequence, is not the largest term of the sequence. Please see the definition of limit superior again : it is  the largest *limit point* of the sequence as a set, or the largest number such that there is a subsequence of the given sequence converging to that point.

Answer (score 0):

Notice

$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \sup}\, x_n = \inf \{x_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $,

and

$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \inf}\, x_n = \sup \{x_{2n-1} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $.

Moreover, $2$ is a lower bound for the set $\left\{2+\frac{3^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\frac{1}{n^2} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$, and $-2$ is an upper bound for the set $\left\{-2-\frac{3^{2n-1}}{(2n-1)!}-\frac{4}{(2n-1)^2}  : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} $.

Also observe that we have $\frac{3^n}{n!} < 2^{6-n}$ whenever $n>6$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. By the Archimedean Property we may find positive integers $N_1$ and $N_2$ such that
\begin{aligned}&N_1  > 7 - \frac{\log\varepsilon}{\log 2}, \text{ and} \\&
N_2\varepsilon > 8 .
\end{aligned}
Set $N=\max\{7, N_1, N_2\}$. So if $n \geq N$, then we have
\begin{equation}\frac{3^n}{n!}+\frac{4}{n^2}<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon .
\end{equation}
So there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{aligned} &x_{2N}<2+\varepsilon, \text{ and} \\& x_{2N-1}>-2-\varepsilon.
\end{aligned}
Therefore, $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \sup}\, x_n =2$ and $\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \inf}\, x_n =-2$.

**Note:** Since $N \geq 7$, we know that $2N-1>N$ and $2N>N$.

Comment: Is there a reason this got down voted? Because I would love to hear it.

Comment: I guess it is because I accidentally had written "$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \sup}\,  = \inf \{x_{2n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $" and "$\underset{n \to \infty}{\lim \inf} = \sup \{x_{2n-1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$", where obviously I did not notice that I forgot to write  "$x_n$". I really wish I knew what sort of person down votes for this. They could have easily edited my answer or left a comment...clearly a lazy ingrate.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a less rigorous but quicker way to look at the problem.

We have 
$$x_n=(-1)^n \left(2+\frac{3^n}{n!}+\frac{4}{n^2}\right)$$

Let's look at 
$$\lvert x_n\rvert=2+\frac{3^n}{n!}+\frac{4}{n^2}$$

We know that
$\dfrac4{n^2}$ is decreasing and $2$ is constant.

The first few terms of $\dfrac{3^n}{n!}$ are
$$\dfrac{3}{1},\,
\dfrac{3\cdot3}{2\cdot1},\,
\dfrac{3\cdot3\cdot3}{3\cdot2\cdot1},\,
\dfrac{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3}{4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1},\,
\dfrac{3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3}{5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1},\cdots$$

which has 2nd and 3rd terms equal and 4th terms onwards decreasing.

All in all, $\lvert x_n\rvert$ will be decreasing from 3rd terms onwards. Hence, $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the lower and upper limits respectively.